# How to marshal this C++ struct?

Tags: c#, struct, vb6, clr, pinvoke

I've been having a horrible time for the last couple of days trying to call an unmanaged dll with C#

#### C++ code

```c++
int _stdcall getVBArrayStrValues(LPSTR t, LPSTR iName, short first, short last,
    LPSAFEARRAY FAR * ppsaStringRead)

typedef struct {
    short readStatus;
    LPVOID vbsValueStr;
} vbStringRead;
```

The existing program called the dll from a VB6 application which initialises the vbsValueStr to be a string 17 characters long `char rtnStr[17];`. Just before the `vbStringRead[]` array is passed by reference.
The dll modifies this array to produce the output.

My guess is that I marshal the struct somehow to be be an `LPArray`. Do I declare the `vbsValueStr` to be an `IntPtr`, or `Byte[]` or `char[]`?

Every attempt I try I get the error:

> Attempt to read or write Protected Memory This is often an indicating that other memory is corrupt

Below is my latest botched attempt.

```
[DllImport("FILENAME.dll")]
public static extern int getVBArrayStrValues(string t, string iName, int first,
    int last, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] ref vbStringRead[] stringRead);


[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct vbStringRead {
    public int readStatus;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string valueStr;
}
```

**EDIT:**

@Matthew Watson's advice has definitely helped. I'm still struggling with the string component of the struct.

I'm currently trying to declare valueStr as an IntPtr and then marshal it as a char (Sorry not sure if that is the best way to describe it)

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public struct vbStringRead
        {
            public int readStatus;
            public IntPtr valueStr;
        }
```

I have tried various ways to set up the the IntPtr so that it is char[17] or byte [17] but it returns the exception "Parameter is incorrect."

Comment: Not a C++ question but a C# pinvoke one. Corrected that for you.

Comment: Looks like the `ppsaStringRead` array is a SAFEARRAY - if so, you should be using UnmanagedType.SafeArray instead of UnmanagedType.LPArray

Comment: That appears to have removed the "Attempt to read or write..." error and is now reporting: "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: ptr". Which is interesting as I don't have a parameter called ptr. I suspect it has to do with the LPVOID.

Comment: Why did you map `short` to `int`?

Comment: Good question, I must have missed that one and will follow that up soon. The existing VB code used int.